# Stored Procedure Validated Using EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule but Fails to Execute at Subscribers

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2019, transactional-replication

Testing a transactional replication pub/sub with over 2.5K articles against a database that has been around for over 20 years and was recently updated to SQLSERVER 2019. There are some modules that do not compile and fail when sent to the subscriber. In order to find and drop these articles, I have been running a script that runs `EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule` against all modules. Only a small percentage, 38 articles do not compile without error.

After taking those 38 articles out of the subscription, only one stored procedure still fails when applied at the subs, and I don't know why.

I can drop/create and alter this SP without error at both the pub and sub. `sp_refreshsqlmodule` does not raise an exception when called against it, however, when applying the snapshot to any subscriber, I get the error below. I guess it is using a sqlmcd, osql or some other tool which may have different validation??

**ERROR:**

```
(Transaction sequence number: 0x0005891300010478004400000000, Command ID: 13770)


Error messages:
⦁    Missing end comment mark '*/'. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 113)
Get help: http://help/113
```

The only part of the SP that has the /* */ comments is in the header. Why does SSMS/SQLSERVER 2019 see this as valid but replicatation kicks it back?

**Stored Procedure:**

```
/*  
Declare @MasterGroupID INT = 28367  
EXEC spDeriveEligiblePaymentDates @MasterGroupID  
GO  
Declare @LeaseRecognitionScheduleID AS IntegerIDTable  
INSERT INTO @LeaseRecognitionScheduleID   
SELECT DISTINCT leaseRecognitionScheduleID from vwleaseFAS13LeaseTerms 
where leaseabstractid = 132976
order by LeaseRecognitionScheduleID  
EXEC spDeriveEligiblePaymentDates null, @LeaseRecognitionScheduleID  
*/  
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[spDeriveEligiblePaymentDates] (@MastergroupID AS INT NULL, @LeaseRecognitionScheduleID AS IntegerIDTable ReadOnly)  
AS  
  BEGIN
  ...
  END
```

Comment: Few hints here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810403/missing-end-comment-mark-error-on-sql-server-2008-not-on-2005

Comment: @SqlWorldWide - Thanks for the link, I did come across that question. It would be ideal to narrow down the exact cause. I could roll through all SP's and remove the header comments, however, I would like to leave those intact, is possible.